# How can I get my RegEx to continue after matching the first occurrence

Tags: python, regex

I am using python regular expressions to extract property address data from a document. I am perfectly matching the first occurrence but the extracting stops there.

How can I manipulate the RegEx strings to keep the parser going?

```
addressRegex = re.compile(r''' 
(
(^[\d]+-?[\d]+)             # street number
\s                          # first seperator
([A-Za-z0-9]+)              # pre directional   
\s                          # second seperator  
([A-Za-z0-9]+)?             # street name
(\s                         # third seperator
[A-Za-z]*                   # street suffix
\s?                         # fourth seperator
[^\w{1}$])?                 # post directional

)
''', re.VERBOSE)

#  Get the text off the clipboard
text = pyperclip.paste()

#  Extract address from text
extractedAddress = addressRegex.findall(text)

allAddresses = []
for addresses in extractedAddress:
    allAddresses.append(addresses[0])

print(allAddresses)
```

The addresses I am extracting come in 4 formats

1. 123 N Main St / 123 N 2nd St  (4 groups with pre-directional)
2. 123 Main St N / 123 2nd St N  (4 groups with post-directional)
3. 123 Main St / 123 2nd St   (3 groups)
4. 123-246 Main St / 123-246 2nd St (3 groups with hyphen between street numbers)

Edit: added sample text, as requested. I am trying to extract the short hand addresses in the top left corner.
[image]

Comment: Remove `^` from the `^[\d]+`?

Comment: Then it pulls all other non-address text that begins with a digit.

Comment: Can you include a sample `text`? Easier to replicate the issue if we can see what text you're feeding into it.

Comment: Example text would make it easier.  But if you've got "other non-address text", you need some way to distinguish between addrs and non-addrs - possibly by specifying explicit enum of street suffixes, like "...\s(St|Ave|Rd)\s..."?  Also worth noting, if you only want the full address strings and aren't using the individual captured words for anything, then change those capture groups to non-capturing groups "(?:...)", it will simplify the output.

Comment: I've added the sample text. Hope that helps.

@KevinPerry Thanks for the feedback! I tried specifying street suffixes. No luck.  
Re: non-capture groups - Sorry, I'm new to this. I understand that (?:) leaves groups out but how would you use that to simplify the code in this instance?

Comment: As the doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall says, "The result depends on the number of capturing groups in the pattern. If there are no groups, return a list of strings matching the whole pattern..."  So you don't have to iterate through the results to pull out the addresses[0] terms.

Comment: Your screenshot is not nearly as helpful as showing us what the actual value of the "text" variable would contain - the actual chars in the string, their order and separators, can make all the difference.  Off-hand, the "other" numbers in the screenshot appear to contain commas, so they shouldn't be matching your regex.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? If not please include the samples as text and not as image. I cannot visualise it.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.